# What makes a tree traversal pre-order or in-order?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

Why is a tree traversal via root, left and right called pre-order? Shouldn't that be in-order, because the root is always first?

It does not makes sense to me why it is called that way, because the root is always the first element.

Comment: The prefix for the search name is the location of the root in the order of the set `(right, root, left)` - therefor `in-order` is when the root is in the middle (not before (=pre) or after (=post))

Comment: @dWinder Should'n it be `(left, root, right)`?

Comment: You are correct - the important thing is that the root is in the middle

Answer (score 7):

We always have the restriction that the left child is visited before the right child.

The main difference is where is the root.

- If the root is **before** both children, we call it preorder.(Root, Left, Right)
- If the root is **after** both children, we call it postorder. (Left, Right, Root)
- If the root is in between both children, we call it  inorder. (Left, Root, Right)

Answer (score 5):

The prefix refers to **when** the content of the root node should be placed.

[image]

Given this tree, you can represent it in various ways:

- **Pre-order**: **Root** is placed first (then **left** and **right** children), so the list will look as follows:

```
[41, 20, 11, 29, 32, 65, 50, 91, 72, 99]
 ^   --------------  ------------------
 |        |                     |
 |        |                     |-----Right sub-tree
 |        | 
 |        |----Left sub-tree
 |
 |------ Root of the tree
```

Inside left and right sub-tree sublists the **preorder** is kept.

- **In-order**: **Left** child is placed (analized if you like) first, then **root** and **right** child. It will look like this:

```
[11, 20, 29, 32, 41, 50, 65, 72, 91, 99]
 --------------  |   ------------------
      |          |            |
      |          |            |------- Right sub-tree
      |          |
      |          |---- Root of the tree
      |
      |----- Left sub-tree
```

Now, first part of the list represents the left sub tree, the root is placed after, and finally, the right sub-tree. Here, **inorder** is also kept inside left and right sub-trees sublists.

<sup>In-order traversal can be seen as a *left-to-right* scanning.</sup>

- **Post-order**: **Left** child analized first, then the **right** child and finally the **root**:

```
[11, 32, 29, 20, 50, 72, 99, 91, 65, 41]
 --------------  ------------------  |
       |                 |           |---- Root of the tree
       |                 |        
       |                 |----- Right sub-tree
       | 
       |------ Left sub-tree
```

Same as the others, root is at the end, but left and right sublist keep the same **postorder** property.

---

Additionally, other posible traversal can be

- **By levels**: elements are placed sorted by their level on the tree, left to right

```
[41, 20, 65, 11, 29, 50, 91, 32, 72, 99]
 |   ------  --------------  ----------
 |      |          |                |-----Level 3
 |      |          |
 |      |          |----- Level 2
 |      |
 |      |------ Level 1
 |
 |----- Level 0 (aka, the root of the tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple tree:

```
  A
 /  \
B    C
```

**Pre-Order traversal**: `ABC`.

The term contains the word `pre`. `pre` means before. So the root is before any of its children. Note that `A` is before both `B` and `C`

**Post order Traversal**: `BCA`

The term contains the word `post`. `post` means after. So the root is after any of its children. Note that `A` is after both `B` and `C`

**Inorder traversal**: `BAC`

The term contains the word `In`. `In` means inside (middle). So the root is in middle of its children. Note that `A` is in between `B` and `C`